# min-height for jquery tabs will affect page automatically scroll

Tags: jquery, tabs, css

here is my code

http://jsfiddle.net/aSCDp/5/

If you please scroll the page down to bottom, and click any links. The page will be automatically scrolled to top.

Is it possible to keep the page stationary when we click the links?

I thought the problem comes from the "min-height" of #container. If I set the "min-height" higher then #tab3, then there is no problem at all.

Moreover, if I replace " $('#tab' + k).fadeIn(500);" with "$('#tab' + k).show();" . The page will not be scrolled to top.

Could you help me to resolve this problem and keep the fadeIn effect?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to fix window scroll offset. In your code:

```js
var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
$('.tabs').hide();
$('#tab' + k).fadeIn(500); //$('#tab' + k).show();
$(window).scrollTop(scrollTop);
```

Comment: I prefer this way, because it's easy for me to change the code. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can set an anchor to the bottom of the DOM, make the colors names *links* and point each of them to the bottom anchor. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aSCDp/7/)